# WinEdt 10.3 - a manual request

Tags: winedt, documentation

Where can I find the WinEdt 10.3 newest manual (from year 2020), any links/references ?
Does this manual also come as a book on Amazon.co.uk ?

Comment: I don't think there is a manual from 2020. The newest I could find dates back to 2017: https://www.winedt.com/download.html#Quick_Guide

Maybe this also helps: http://www.winedt.org/migrate.html

Comment: Did you consider emailing a query to support@winedt.com?